# Serializable classes and the == operator

Tags: java, serialization, equals

Here is the source code of the String.equals method:

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = count;
        if (n == anotherString.count) {
        char v1[] = value;
        char v2[] = anotherString.value;
        int i = offset;
        int j = anotherString.offset;
        while (n-- != 0) {
            if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
            return false;
        }
        return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Since String is Serializable, does it make sense to use the == operator in the String.equals method? If we try to compare two different String objects, maybe with the same memory address, located on different VM, will this work correctly?

In my own code I use equals method to compare two strings. I know what == does. I am asking if it make sense to have a == comparison in the equals method of the String class.

Comment: Some answers below are for a different question.

Comment: Based on your comments below, what you misunderstand is what Serializable actually means.

Comment: I've edited the question based on the OP's comments. Is this what you really meant to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Serializable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) means that an instance of the class can be converted into bytes and back into a an object instance using Java's default serialization mechanisms. When an object is deserialized, a new object instance is created based on the bytes and that instance exists in the JVM where it was deserialized. Serialization/deserialization does not magically make the same object instance accessible in multiple JVMs, but it just creates new object instances which are copies of each other.

Two JVMs cannot share object instances, so it's not possible that the == operator could be used to compare the addresses of object instances from different address spaces.

Answer (score 3):

It makes perfect sense to use the == because if both the instance of string point to same reference they have to be equal so no need to compare the characters

Comment: String is Serializable. If we try to compare two different String objects, maybe with the same memory address, located on different VM, will this work correctly?

Comment: If I'm able to use a string in a JVM, then the String is in this JVM. If it were in another JVM, I wouldn't be able to use it. Serializable only means that it's possible to transform the object into a stream of bytes to send it elsewhere. But when it's deserialized, it becomes another string instance in the JVM which has deserialized it. It's not some sort of symlink to the string in the other JVM.

Comment: even if your objects are shared across different VM, when you are trying to do the comparision, both the instances will be present in the VM where you are trying to compare the objects, so it should work fine.

Comment: What the OP needs to realize is that the fact that it is a String or Serializable is irrelevant.  You should do this check in any equals for the reason described.

Comment: the other if is to compare the characters, essentially what we want is stringA.equals(stringB) should evaluate true if their content is same. So the first IF checks if the instances are same: if same its guaranteed that both string will be equal in their content. The second if checks for two different instances of string with same character content.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it makes sense, because java uses a pool of Strings, so when you create a String without using the new keyword, as long as both reference variables are the same String == will always be true.

Say you have "" in your string pool, if you do

```
String a = "";
String b = "";
```

Since "" is in the string pool, they will in fact be pointing to the same memory location and therefore

```
a == b
```

Would be true

In fact as long as you don't use

```
 String c = new String("");
```

The reference variable will always be pointing to the "" in the String pool.

However when you use the new keyword a new memory allocation is created outside of the String pool. Therefore if you do:

```
 c == b
```

This will return false, because the reference to b is in the String pool, but the reference for c is not, it is outside the pool

However if we did

```
 String d = c.intern()
 d == b
```

This will return true, what intern does per the comments on the String class is

Returns a canonical representation for the string object.
A pool of strings, initially empty, is maintained privately by the class String.

When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a string equal to this String object as determined by the equals(Object) method, then the string from the pool is returned. Otherwise, this String object is added to the pool and a reference to this String object is returned.

It follows that for any two strings s and t, s.intern() == t.intern() is true if and only if s.equals(t) is true.

As some already pointed out when the object is deserialized on the other JVM, it will be using that JVM String pool

Comment: Its actually not creating a new allocation outside the string pool. If you check c.intern()==a.intern() you will see that they equal. So new String() only creates a new reference on a pointer which points on the same intern representation. But the reference on the pointer is different from the reference which is handed over from the StringPool aka Literal cache.

Comment: I believe that is incorrect, what .intern() does is create that String in the global String pool if it wasn't there already and return a reference to this newly created String in the pool. Which means there could be a memory allocation outside the pool for "" and one in the pool with ""

Comment: @fyr these remarks are so mangled as to be completely meaningless. The parts of it that are intelligible are incorrect. The constant pool is created by the compiler and cannot be modified at runtime. Ergo String.intern() does not modify the constant pool. If the string is already in the constant pool, that reference will be returned, otherwise a pooled reference is returned.

Comment: @EJP Please read the java documentation before stating that someone says something wrong. [DocReference] (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) or the 1.6 version: (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29)

Comment: @fyr please tell me what part of that document contradicts what I have said here.

Comment: @EJP "When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a string equal to this String object as determined by the equals(Object) method, then the string from the pool is returned. Otherwise, this String object is added to the pool and a reference to this String object is returned. "

Comment: @fyr so now tell me which part of that says that the constant pool is modifiable at runtime, and specifically that it is modified by String.intern(). Your answer conflates the constant pool and the pool used by String.intern(). They are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

This IF case in the java api is an optimization. Because the Virtual Machine holds a String Cache and optimizes some (not all) Strings to literals. Some literals hold the same object reference.

With my JDK e.g.

```
String a = "ABCD";
String b = "ABCD";
if (a==b)
```

equals to true. Because both are in the Literal cache of my jvm. But its not enough to compare the object reference because not every String is saved in the literal cache.

e.g.

```
String a = new String("ABCD");
String b = new String("ABCD");
if (a==b)
```

will always be false because you explicitly call for a new object reference.

But even in the above case

```
if(a.intern()==b.intern())
```

will also equal to true.

There is also another post on this: [Using static variables for Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802032/using-static-variables-for-strings)

Comment: *All* equal literals refer to the same String object in the constant pool, and this is done by the compiler, not by the VM.

Comment: @EJP: see the other comments below. Please dont state things which are simply not true.

Comment: there are no other comments below. What part of what I wrote is 'simply not true'?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are speaking about the following code snippet:

```
if (this == anObject) {
    return true;
}
```

It makes sense to use the == operator, since it will be only true when both strings are pointing to the same memory address. This is probably done in java.lang.String to optimize string comparison when string literals are used. You can check http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200409/ScjpTipLine-StringsLiterally.html for detailed description of how string literals are pooled in Java.

Answer (score 0):

> If we try to compare two different
>   String objects, maybe with the same
>   memory address, located on different
>   VM, will this work correctly?

You can't do that. There is no way of comparing Strings in two VMs, with or without the == operator. Your question therefore isn't *about* anything. You would have to get them both into the same VM, whereupon you would call String.equals().

The == test is just a shorthand to avoid going through all the rest of the code. It is has nothing to do with Serialization whatsoever. And different VMs cannot possibly come into it.

Answer (score -4):

No. Since "String" is not a primative type using == simply compares the address of the object and not the contents itself. By executing:

```
String a = "ABCD";
String b = "ABCD";

if (a == b)
```

You would get false because although string a & string b are the same their representations in memory are different.

The .equals() method is used to compare Strings (also, Objects) within Java as it compares the contents of the Object.

Comment: In that sample code you would very probably get a true, because javac will optimize it so that both variables point to the same literal.

Comment: I use equals method to compare two strings. I know what == does. I am asking if it make sense to have a == comparison in the equals method of the String.

Comment: It does because on the equals method it is comparing chars which are primitives.